# How do I check whether my python daemon is actually running i.e. get logs for the process?

Tags: python, debugging, daemon

I am daemonizing a python app using this sample code http://web.archive.org/web/20131017130434/http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/

Goal: I need to daemonize it to make it deployable via an ansible script.

Upon running the daemon i can see that the daemon was created as the pid file does have a pid. But i can't ereally figure out whether the daemon is running. How can i access the logs for the process that will give me an indication of whether it is running or not?

I use `ps -a | grep pid-in-pidFile` to see if the process exists and it appears but it's still not enough info.

```
class DaemonImpl(Daemon):
    """ Overrides Daemon's run method """

    def run(self):
        """ Add implementation here """
        while True:
            sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    daemon = DaemonImpl("/path/to/pidfile")
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        if 'start' == sys.argv[1]:
            daemon.start()
        elif 'stop' == sys.argv[1]:
            daemon.stop()
        elif 'restart' == sys.argv[1]:
            daemon.restart()
        else:
            print("Unknown command")
            sys.exit(2)
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        print("usage: %s start|stop|restart" % sys.argv[0])
        sys.exit(2)
else:
    print(__name__ + ": Is unknown")
```

I expect to be able to see logs of the daemon process i have started.